# Cast hexadecimal to int for MySQL import

Tags: mysql

First, I can not re-export this, so I'm stuck with this file.

In the sample posted below, values for an INT column are hexadecimal.  I think.  Values such as 0X31 need to import as 1.  Instead they import as 49.  I'm guessing that this might be the ascii equivalent.  I need to import 0x31 as 1, 0x32 as 2, etc.  How would I do this?

I would also be OK with a text editor that is smart enough to search and replace these values.  I have thousands of questionid's so I don't want to do this manually e.g. search "0x31" replace with "1".

Here is the import sample.

`REPLACE INTO 'qa_sharedevents' ('entitytype', 'entityid', 'questionid', 'lastpostid', 'updatetype', 'lastuserid', 'updated') VALUES 
('Q', '1', 0x31, '1', '', '1', '2012-03-08 23:45:56'),
('U', '1', 0x31, '1', '', '1', '2012-03-08 23:45:56'),
('Q', '1', 0x31, '3', '', '', '2012-03-09 02:23:54'),
('T', '17', 0x31, '1', '', '1', '2012-03-08 23:45:56'),
('Q', '2', 0x32, '2', '', '1', '2012-03-09 01:28:36'),
('U', '1', 0x32, '2', '', '1', '2012-03-09 01:28:36'),
('Q', '2', 0x32, '2', 'E', '1', '2012-03-09 01:30:27'),
('U', '1', 0x32, '2', 'E', '1', '2012-03-09 01:30:27'),`

Comment: `0x31` *is* `49`, not `1`. What is the replacement criteria? Remove any prefix of `0x3`?

Comment: `0x31` is 49, but `0x31` is also the ASCII code for `1`, as is 49 in decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char) function:

```
mysql> select char(0x31), char(0x35);
+------------+------------+
| char(0x31) | char(0x35) |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | 5          |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL subtring function. Try this on your mysql client to see how it works:

select substring('0x31',-1,1);